# Best way to replace a table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a web app running off a database table that is generated from a csv file.

This table needs to update frequently from the csv.  The table needs to match the csv exactly, i.e. if a record no longer exists in the csv it should no longer exist in the table or it should be soft deleted.

What is the proper way to do this?

It seems the easiest way would be:

1. create temp table
2. import csv to temp table
3. drop live table
4. rename temp table to live table name

This will be scripted inside the app so I don't think the downtime will be much as dropping table and renaming shouldn't take too long but it doesn't seem like the safest way to do things as there is a moment where no table exists.

I tried to instead do:

1. create temp table
2. import csv to temp table
3. update records in live table with data from temp table
4. delete records in live table that don't exist in temp table

In theory that sounded better but it is extremely slow.  The first method just takes a few seconds.  The second method the update takes a really long time, I let it run for 10 minutes before cancelling it as it wasn't finished.

I did the update like this:

```
update table_name as t
set
  column1 = t.column1,
  column2 = t.column2,
  -- etc..
from table_name_temp
```

What is the proper way to handle this situation?

Comment: `... I let it run for 10 minutes before cancelling it as it wasn't finished....` Maybe put a semicolon after your UPDATE statement? Also: is there a WHERE clause on the UPDATE? Do you suppress idempotent updates ? What is `-- etc.` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is wrap your simple solution within a transaction. This will ensure that your steps are executed atomically. See: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-transactions.htm for more info.

Postgres support [`ALTER TABLE .. RENAME`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html).

- http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-rename-table/
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/100779/how-to-atomically-replace-table-data-in-postgresql

Comment: Note that in Postgres (and SQL Server) the renaming of the table can be part of the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

The *rename table* method only works if there are no constraints or triggers involved.

In most cases the new table's contents will not differ too much from the old version; the trick is to suppres updates that don't change anything.

In steps:

---

- create temp table
- import csv to temp table
- delete records from live table that don't exist in temp table # **deletes**
- delete records **from temp table** that are EXACTLY THE SAME in live table # idempotent updates
- update records in live table with data from temp table # **actual** updates
- insert records into live table from temp table that dont yest exist # **inserts**